# android launching toast through javascriptinterface in webview

Tags: android, android-webview

My android app has a WebView in which i have a button in webview. When clicking the button in the web page i should display a toast from javascript through JavaScriptInterface.

I referred this example from android developer site http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

When i implemented this javascript and android code, Toast appears only in Android 2.2 but not in any other API level.

Someone help me if you had crossed over this error problem???
I couldn't find any solution for this... Please help me out..

Regards,
SanthoshPulliman.

Comment: Hi Guys... I got the way :):) the example application works fine in android devices but not in emulator. It works only in android 2.2 emulator but not in any other version neither 2.3 or 2.3+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the lower level API, but the bridge from JavaScript to Java is broken in 2.3+. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987.

Comment: What should i do to overcome this ??

Comment: Any alternative way to achive the JavaScriptInterface in  2.3+ ??

Comment: I got the way :):) the example application works fine in android devices but not in emulator. It works only in android 2.2 emulator but not in any other version neither 2.3 or 2.3+